# How to trigger UIButton target event before parent TapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, events, uibutton, touch

It's a simple question,
I have a `UIButton` with a target action

```
addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
func buttonPressed()
{
    self.selected = !self.selected
}
```

This button is the child of a parent `UIView`

```
containerView.addSubview(button)
```

I add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the container

```
let tapG = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "toggleView:")
containerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapG)
```

in **func toggleView(gest:UIGestureRecognizer)** I check the status of my button.

The problem is that in `toggleView()`, the status of the button has not been set... **YET!**

**EDIT**

if I do

```
print(button.selected)
```

I only get the button value BEFORE the touch event, not the new one.

any idea?

Comment: I found a way to "solve" the issue by changing the button control event to TouchDown instead of TouchUp. That way, the Button trigger is called before the end of the GestureRecognizer

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
func toggleView(gest:UIGestureRecognizer)
```

to

```
func toggleView(gest:UITapGestureRecognizer)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks but it doesn't help. I'm just using superclass as parameter, easier to manage code if you want to change your GestureRecognizer type

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly get what you are trying to accomplish, If you want to perform certain action on button click and another action when tapped outside in containerView then you can do

```
-(void)toggleView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gest{
     CGPoint tapLocation = [gest loactionInView:containerView];
     if(CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, tapLocation)){
         // Tapped on Button
      }
     else{
         // tapped outside in containerView
      }
}
```

Note: As am not learning swift, i gave snippet in Objective-C. you should be able to translate it into swift easily :)

Comment: I'd like the button TouchUpInside to be triggered BEFORE the tapGestureRecognizer on its parent view.

Comment: I think it's related to FirstResponder but I don't quite figure out how to make it work